# Should I use the ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC React.js and Redux template?

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to create my first ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC React web application and have chosen to use the provided template but I'm struggling to find out how to reference jQuery from within a React component even though jQuery is included within the package.json file. I'm getting the impression I need to use something like Webpack but cannot find anything definitive.

I've been trawling the web and I'm now wondering if starting with the template is the right approach. Can anyone please point me in the direction of any form of tutorial/videos or any books that take you step by step through the various stages of building a React website with a ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC backend?

Comment: From Review: Unfortunately [questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools, or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Comment: i have implemented reactjs.net with redux and getting error
JsScriptException: Script threw an exception.
JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore.JsRt.JsErrorHelpers.ThrowIfError(JsErrorCode errorCode)

JsRuntimeException: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Login)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Login) in connect options.

can you please help me
Thanks in advance .